# c++ multiple if statements. Why else statement also executes?

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

When I execute the if statement right before the else statement, the code will execute properly. But when I execute the if statement that is away from the else statement, the c++ will execute the chosen 'if statement' but the 'else statement' will also execute. What is happening there?

I know how to fix my code, without the else statement executing problem going on.
I just want to know what is c++ doing or how the flow works when I put two or more if statement plus the else statement. Why the else statement executes when the if statement is already executed?

For example in this code:
If ever I enter a value lower than 160, the first if statement will execute but the else statement will also execute after it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    float h;

    cout << "What is your height in centimeters?";
    cin >> h;
    if (h <= 160) {
        cout << "You are too small!";
    }
    if (h >= 190) {
        cout << "You are too tall!";
    }
    else {
        cout << "You have the appropriate height. You are qualified!";
    }
}
```

Comment: The first `if` statement and the second `if ... else` statement are independent. The compiler looks at the first `if` and decides if it should be executed, and then it goes on to the second `if ... else` block. Since `h` is not larger than 190, the else part is executed.

Comment: missing `else` after first `if` so just a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the c++ will execute the chosen 'if statement' but the 'else statement' will also execute. What is happening there?

These two `if` statements are separate and the `else` is part of the second `if` statement:

```
/* One if statement block  ************************/
 *       if(h<=160){
 *          cout << "You are too small!";
 *            
 *        }
/*************************************************/

/* Second if Statement block, "else" is part of it. Only one of them can be true */
 *        if(h>=190){ 
 *            cout << "You are too tall!";
 *            
 *        }
 *        else{ 
 *            cout << "You have the appropriate height. You are qualified!";
 *            
 *        }
/*****************************************************/
```

1. **IF** h is less than 160, first statement is **true** and you will see `"You are too small!"` in output.
2. The second **IF** is checked then, and if first was **true**, second will obviously be **false** because `h` is less than 160. If it is **false**, `else` block will be executed.

Whenever you write:

```
if (...)  {}
else  {}
```

One of the above gets executed i.e, `if` block OR `else` block.

Note that there is `else if` statement as well, which you can use like:'

```
    if (h <= 160) {  //1st check
        cout << "You are too small!";
    }
    else if (h >= 190) { //second check
        cout << "You are too tall!";
    }
    else { //third
        cout << "You have the appropriate height. You are qualified!";
    }
```

Now these three are part of one conditional check. Only one of them will run at a time.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to understand this outcome is to realise that you have two completely independent *if* statements.  If h <= 160, the statement in the first *if* block will execute.  Then, entirely separately, the program will output one of the two statements in the second *if...else* block, depending on whether h >= 190 or not:

```
if (h <= 160) {
    cout << "You are too small!";
}
// the following is a separate statement
if (h >= 190) {
    cout << "You are too tall!";
}
else {
    cout << "You have the appropriate height. You are qualified!";
}
```

What you really want to do is execute the second *if...else* block only if the first *if* statement is false.  The clearest way to illustrate this would be to enclose the second *if...else* block inside the *else* term for the first *if* statement:

```
if (h <= 160) {
    cout << "You are too small!";
}
else {
    if (h >= 190) {
        cout << "You are too tall!";
    }
    else {
        cout << "You have the appropriate height. You are qualified!";
    }
}
```

Hopefully the indentation helps you to see the program flow.

There is a simpler way to accomplish the same thing, which may be clearer to read once you understand the program flow logic, and is particularly helpful to cut down on the number of {} blocks and indentation as more *if* conditions are added:

```
if (h <= 160) {
    cout << "You are too small!";
}
else if (h >= 190) {
    cout << "You are too tall!";
}
else {
    cout << "You have the appropriate height. You are qualified!";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> If ever I enter a value lower than 160, the first if statement will execute but the else statement will also execute after it.

That's how `if` statement works - all as expected.

- the first `if` is executed because the condition is met (h < 160). Note: now  it's all DONE with that first `if`.
- the second `if` is totally independent of the first `if`. And because the condition is not met, the `else` is executed.